# C# return File opens notepad instead of showing in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm doing an MVC4 tutorial.  I'm using the line

```
return File(Server.MapPath("~/Content/site.css"), "text/css");
```

which in the video renders in the browser, but when I do it the file opens in notepad.  How do I make the file render in the browser?

Comment: Change the file association in windows for .css from notepad to your browser of choice

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did that, but then I'm prompted to open or save.  If I pick open then the downloaded programs dialog appears.  It still doesn't appear in the browser.

Comment: BTW, I'm using VS 2010 Pro SP1.  The video is using VS2012.

Comment: You could try setting the http header Content-Disposition to inline. I.e. "Content-Disposition: inline;"

Comment: Could you please explain how to do that?